# IE 9 ignores margin-bottom of last element on page

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9, margin

If I add a margin-bottom to the last element on a page (a div in my case), it's ignored in IE 9. In other words, the last element is flush with the bottom of the window.

Is this a known issue? It works as expected in Chrome/Firefox.

Comment: It's been four years but it's worth noting that I'm experiencing this exact issue in Internet Explorer 11. In fact, I've noticing something even stranger: the margin is being taken into account when calculating positioning (for instance, with `position: relative` on nearby elements or with `display: table-cell`) how it's not being taken into account when determining the height of the parent. I'm actively experimenting to find a solution. I noticed I could create an ugly hack by applying `margin-bottom: 0; padding-bottom: xxx;` to `:last-child`, however this isn't ideal.

Answer (score 1):

This is true if the divs are floated but the containing div is not.

```
<div class='outer'>
   <div class='inner'>dfsdfs</div>
   <div class='inner'>sdfsdf</div>
   <div class='inner'>vxcvxv</div>
   <div class='inner'>cvxcv</div>
</div>

div.outer {
   background: green;
}

div.inner {
   height: 50px;
   background: red;
   margin-bottom: 50px;
   display:block;
   float:left;
   clear:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have setup a simple test to see whether or not I could reproduce your issue. First, following your lead, I provided some HTML - being sure to make the last element a `div`:

```
<div></div><div></div>
<div></div><div></div>
```

Then some styles:

```
div {
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

I then proceeded to test IE9 on Windows 7 using [browserstack](http://browserstack.com) - I was unable to reproduce your issue. In my case, the browser properly rendered the appropriate spacing around the last element.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/EgjVn/